# How to use PHP CURL to bypass cross domain

Tags: php, curl, cross-domain

I need PHP to submit paramaters from one domain to another. JavaScript is not an option for my situation. I'm now trying to use CURL with PHP, but have not been successful in bypassing the cross domain.

From domain_A, I have a page with the following PHP with CURL script:

```
if (_iscurl()){
    echo "<p>CURL is enabled</p>";
    $url = "http://domain_B/process.php?id=123&amt=100&jsonp=?";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo "<p>Finished operations</p>";
}
else{
    echo "CURL is disabled";
}
?>
```

I am not getting any results, so I am assuming that the PHP CURL script is not successful. Any ideas to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Well, its bit late. But adding this answer for further readers who might face similar issue. This issue arises some times when we are sending php curl request from a domain hosted over **http** to a domain hosted over **https (http over ssl)**.

Just add below code snippet before curl execution.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using false in `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` doesn't return anything by curl. make it `true`(or `1`)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: Hi, the parameter has been set to true, i.e. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); but I'm still getting the same results. Could it be that there's a port blocking the call?

Comment: I've included an error tracking:

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
  echo 'error#:' . curl_errno($ch) . '/ error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

I got error#7, unable to connect to host. However, our admin advised me that all ports are open and therefore no firewall is applied

Comment: Please update your code if you used `true` for return-transfer. Also, add this to your curl `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and it will generate some output. Show that output to me.

Comment: Hi,the return-transfer is set to true and I've added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`. I've used `print CURLOPT_VERBOSE;`. I'm getting a value of 41. I'm now checking what the value means

Comment: The URL I'm trying to call is published on port 1337. I was wondering if this is the root of the problem? Maybe this should be set at port 80?

Comment: If you can browse it from browser, then curl should do it. However try to set the port through this option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 1337);`. I never used it, doing experiment on you :D

Comment: Hi, just tried out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 1337);` but still getting the same results. I really think there's something in our server that's blocking PHP+CURL call.

Comment: Is there any chance to get the actual url? Disguised under tinyurl will do? Otherwise everything is blackbox to me :(

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that I'm not at liberty to divulge the url, even in tinyurl format :-) But here's the weird part, if I reverse the process- before it was domain A submitting parameters to domain B via PHP Curl, and now its domain B submitting parameters to domain A via PHP Curl using the same script, the whole process works. It must be a server issue, but the question now is- what issue is it?