# CURL get page emty?

Tags: php, curl

I have a very weird case as follows :

This my CURL function :

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 500;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

I have a txt file content link line by line. I get all that link to an array and tried to get content :

```
$itemLink = file($LinkFile);
if(empty($itemLink)){
    echo "endFile";
    exit();
}
echo $itemLink[0]; //https://stackoverflow.com
echo get_data($itemLink[0]);
```

The result return empty but when i tried put direct link to my function like this :

```
echo get_data('https://stackoverflow.com');
```

Of course i can get full page normally.

Anybody knows what going on ?

Comment: See if `curl_getinfo()` can help you debug your curl request. Does `get_data(trim($itemLink[0]))` help at all by any chance?

Comment: trim($itemLink[0]) working perfect.Thank you very much !

Comment: I'll turn my comment into an answer, so you can mark it as an accepted answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `file()` to read your document, I have a feeling you're getting the line endings in your URL and cURL is failing to handle the request.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used.

to remove any superfluous line ending characters from the URL.

```
$itemLink = file( $LinkFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
```

---

If this is not sufficient use the `trim()` function

```
echo get_data( trim( $itemLink[0] ) );
```

or

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim( $url ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe a http > https thing?

Previously answered

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

source: [How to use PHP CURL to bypass cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676866/how-to-use-php-curl-to-bypass-cross-domain)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem as the question asker states that `get_data('https://stackoverflow.com')` can be called.

Comment: a not recommended approach